# Symfony Panther shows errors in chrome console err_tunnel_connection_failed when using proxy server

Tags: symfony-panther

Scraping using Symfony Panther works fine, but when I preform the same scrape using a proxy, the requested website will not load resources. I get errors in my google chrome console "err_tunnel_connection_failed"

Here is my Client set up

```
$args = [
        '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
        '--window-size=1600,1100',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--proxy-server=http://' . config('services.panther.proxy_host') . ':' . config('services.panther.proxy_port')
    ];

    // create a chrome client
    return Client::createChromeClient(base_path('drivers/chromedriver'), $args, []);
```

If I remove the `--proxy-server=...` everything works fine.

Any ideas what is going on here and how to fix?

Comment: Is it a `http` proxy? Or `https`? or `tcp`

Comment: What kind of proxy did you setup? Socks might need `socks://`

Comment: It's an http proxy. I'm loading a sign up page. With the proxy enabled, I'm able to see the sign up page, and fill in the form, but the submit relies on a js script being loaded, but that script does not load, "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED". So when the form submits there is a javascript error "ReferenceError"

Comment: You need to provide more details, logs from the proxy, protocol of the requested resource, etc. Put the information into the question, not as a comment.